# How to know file download progress status in server-side Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

Currently, I download byte arrays as files using JsInterop.

Here is my JS file:

```
function downloadFile(fileName, base64String) {
    const url = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + base64String;
    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
}
```

And here is a method in my razor component:

```
async Task DownloadFile(byte[] file)
{
    ShowMessage("Start");
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFile", "FileName", Convert.ToBase64String(file));
    ShowMessage("End");
}
```

This code works, and I am able to download files. My issue is that I cannot implement the progress bar, or even show the loading spinner because `await JSRuntime` has no idea about an actual file download size and its progress. JSRuntime only launches the process of downloading and immediately continues to the next line of code.
In the code above ShowMessage("Start") and ShowMessage("End") are both shown one after another as soon as I click the download button, but the file in the browser downloads much later (depending on the file size).

How may I await the download process and execute relevant code only when the file has been downloaded? And it would be even better if I could read downloaded bytes to show a progress bar with percentages.

Update: for test purposes, I upload the file from the browser and store it in a byte[] variable. Then I download the same file from the variable using JS. Even though I store the file in the memory, it still takes time to download the file. I suppose that when I store a file in memory, it is already on my PC (client), and should download immediately. But instead, my window gets frozen for the duration of downloading the file. Tested on 6 - 11- 20 MB files. The bigger file, the more I have to wait for it to download.

Comment: Once you have the `base64String` the content is already in the browser. I don't think it's possible to monitor the progress of saving the file from the browser's memory. Perhaps you should be using the javascript fetch api to stream the file from the server, which can have a progress bar.

Comment: File download progress is not possible with your design. It also seems to have a memory leak and will probably fail when it hits the Signal-R data limit (default 32k).  Suggest looking at the MS [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @Yogi, I changed my implementation as is shown in an example code. Now it works as expected. However, I still have no idea how to show the progress

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should be show message **ShowMessage("Start")** and **ShowMessage("End");** in function downloadFile at JS

Comment: I think that will not help. I changed my method call to var ```result = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("downloadFile", "FileName", Convert.ToBase64String(file));``` and in JS file I return true at the end of the script. JS returns true before the file has downloaded

Comment: Js will never ever wait for your response. It is synchronous process which execute your code line by line.

Comment: And how may I handle JS code results in C#? I cannot move all my post-download logic to JS. I need feedback from JS indicating that the JS part of the code is completed (or failed)

Comment: @Yogi's comment from the previous answer solved my problem